# Motorcycle Lithium Battery - Potential Parasitic Drain

Tags: motorcycle, battery, charging

I have a track racing motorcycle with a lithium battery, the battery has gone flat on two separate occasions as a result of standing for a period of time. The first time the bike was standing for about 3-4 months and the battery had gone completely dead and the second time, the bike was standing for less than a month and the battery could still turn on the clocks but the engine wouldn't start.

From my understanding, a lithium battery should be able to hold a good charge for much longer without going flat, so I suspect there is a parasitic drain somewhere.

Firstly, how would I test if there is a parasitic drain and secondly how would I find the cause of the of the parasitic drain?

Thanks
Willem

Comment: The LiFePO4 chemistry has a substantially lower self-discharge rate, so can sit on a shelf much longer than most lead-acid batteries, with Odyssey  (pure lead) being the exception. On an Ah:Ah comparison, the LiFePO4 battery is considerably more expensive, but can output more cranking amps per Ah, so it is not necessary to have the same Ah as lead acid to start a vehicle, thus price is reduced. The issue will be that battery capacity is drained much faster due to the reduced Ah capacity. My LiFePO4 battery will be drained by my alarm in about one month, but lead acid would take 3-4 months.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like with a car.  Remove the negative battery cable.  Get your multimeter, set it to DCA (DC Amps).  Use 10A mode if its available.  Connect it between the negative post and the cable.  Reading should be < 50ma.  If its over this, start pulling fuses until you see what makes it drop.  When you find what is causing the draw, find out why it is not shutting off.